# How to delete rows in a dataframe that correspond to missing rows in another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes with two columns each (Date and data). The lenght of the columns differs. What I want to do is to delete the rows in df1 that are not in df2 by Date.

An example will clarify. These are my dataframes:

```
df1 = cbind(data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2018-11-1"), as.Date("2020-02-1"), by = "months"), stringsAsFactors = F), data.frame(Data = rnorm(16, 0, 1), stringsAsFactors = F))

         Date        Data
1  2018-11-01  1.09433662
2  2018-12-01 -0.27538189
3  2019-01-01 -0.19712728
4  2019-02-01  0.99852535
5  2019-03-01 -0.50760024
6  2019-04-01 -0.43127396
7  2019-05-01  0.90685965
8  2019-06-01  0.51510503
9  2019-07-01 -0.39070644
10 2019-08-01  1.27976428
11 2019-09-01 -0.63845519
12 2019-10-01 -0.05489751
13 2019-11-01 -0.87745923
14 2019-12-01  0.18082375
15 2020-01-01  0.08852416
16 2020-02-01  1.50827788

df2= cbind(data.frame(Date = df1$Date[c(1:5,7:9,11:13,15:16)]), data.frame(Data = c(1.09433662,-0.27538189, 0.99852535,-0.50760024,-0.43127396, 0.90685965,-0.39070644, 1.27976428,-0.63845519,-0.05489751,-0.87745923, 0.18082375, 1.50827788)))


         Date        Data
1  2018-11-01  1.09433662
2  2018-12-01 -0.27538189
3  2019-01-01  0.99852535
4  2019-02-01 -0.50760024
5  2019-03-01 -0.43127396
6  2019-05-01  0.90685965
7  2019-06-01 -0.39070644
8  2019-07-01  1.27976428
9  2019-09-01 -0.63845519
10 2019-10-01 -0.05489751
11 2019-11-01 -0.87745923
12 2020-01-01  0.18082375
13 2020-02-01  1.50827788
```

What I want now is that `df1` is reduced to the same length as `df2` by deleting the rows that are not in `df2`. The rows to be deleted correspond to the missing months in `df2`.

The result would be this for `df1`:

```
#df1 where the rows corresponding to the missing months in df2 have been deleted

     Date         Data

1  2018-11-01  1.09433662
2  2018-12-01 -0.27538189
3  2019-01-01 -0.19712728
4  2019-02-01  0.99852535
5  2019-03-01 -0.50760024
6  2019-05-01  0.90685965
7  2019-06-01  0.51510503
8  2019-07-01 -0.39070644
9 2019-09-01 -0.63845519
10 2019-10-01 -0.05489751
11 2019-11-01 -0.87745923
12 2020-01-01  0.08852416
13 2020-02-01  1.50827788
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`semi_join` from dplyr does what you are looking for. Note that your copied the data from df2 as the output example.

```
library(dplyr)

semi_join(df1, df2, by = "Date")

         Date        Data
1  2018-11-01  0.38376758
2  2018-12-01 -0.28738352
3  2019-01-01  1.79556305
4  2019-02-01 -0.34680836
5  2019-03-01  0.57803280
6  2019-05-01  1.96801082
7  2019-06-01  0.38448708
8  2019-07-01  0.39829417
9  2019-09-01  0.94912096
10 2019-10-01 -0.04469681
11 2019-11-01  0.32008546
12 2020-01-01  1.09054839
13 2020-02-01 -1.45438502
```

and `anti_join` shows the records that should be removed.

```
anti_join(df1, df2, by = "Date")

        Date       Data
1 2019-04-01  2.1303783
2 2019-08-01  1.6907800
3 2019-12-01 -0.8593388
```